# Calling async method from Page_Load of webforms

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webforms, async-await

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204450/call-async-method-in-page-load) is a question related to my question i found, which did not work.

In my Page load method of web forms I want to call async method

`void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I want to call async method because I want to be able to call the `GetUserInfoAsync` method of `IdentityModel`

This is what I have

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");

        GetUserClaims(token).Wait();
    }

    public  async Task GetUserClaims(string token)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
        {
            Address = "https://localhost:44367/connect/userinfo",
            Token = token,
        });
        var result = response.Claims;
    }
```

Current problem is I never reach `result = response.claims` part.

```
GetUserClaims(token).Wait();
```

was based upon the answer to the question I linked above.

The other option I tried was use the PageAsyncTask and RegisterAsyncTask as mentioned in one of the option in the answer.

```
    PageAsyncTask t = new PageAsyncTask(GetUserClaims(token));
```

but I get red squiggly thing which complains saying

```
cannot convert from System.Threading.Task.Task to System.Func<System.Threading.Task.Task>
```

Comment: "*is a question related to my question i found which did not work*" why didn't it work

Comment: I have detailed explanation in question I suppose. I have explained what I tried as per the answer mentioned in that question and, what happend when I tried those options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely can't make the Page_Load event handler `async void`, as is suggested by the linked question, then the proper way would be:

```
GetUserClaims(token).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

To avoid the [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) which happens when you call `Wait()`.

You would also need to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to all nested async calls to ensure that the execution resumes in the same context:

```
UserInfoResponse response = await client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
{
    Address = "https://localhost:44367/connect/userinfo",
    Token = token,
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Tried it and still cannot reach `var result = response.Claims;` part of GetUserClaims method. I don't know if the problem is from IdentityModel's GetUserInfoAsync method

Answer (score 2):

Actually this helped

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");
        PageAsyncTask t = new PageAsyncTask(() => GetUserClaims(token));
        // Register the asynchronous task.
        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(t);

        // Execute the register asynchronous task.
        Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
        //GetUserClaims(token).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();          
    }
```