# How to make async task not stall on response

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have to upgrade to Sendgrid v3 API... The email send works (I get the email), but it never returns from the task. What am I missing?

Here is the code I am using. The Label1.Text line does not execute, it never executes past var response.

Thank you!

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TrainingWebsite
{
public partial class sendgrid : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Execute().Wait();
        Label1.Text = "worked?";
    }

    static async Task Execute()
    {
        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY_SYSTEM");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("email@domain.com", "name");
        var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        var to = new EmailAddress("email@domain.com", "name");
        var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about your specific enviroment (Looks like ASP? Never used it) but that kind of thing usually happens because the waiting thread is the same as the one that would process the async scheduling. So, by calling `Wait`, you're hogging the very thread that would run the continuation of your `Execute`, so it never does and thus the task never ends. [This question from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204450/call-async-method-in-page-load) says you should use `RegisterAsyncTask` instead. Note that there might be a more modern/appropriate way to do it since then.